# Windows 11 not booting after fresh installation

Tags: windows-11, efi

Recently I posted a question when my Windows 11 installation failed to boot. I assumed this was due to me changing a EnableVirtualizationBasedSecurity group policy, but being unable to recover from that state, I backed up all my data and reinstalled windows.

However - the issue persists. I installed windows 11 form a newly created installation thumb drive. The installation process went as it should until the first reboot. Then I ran into the same error my previous installation had: I get a blue screen, code SYSTEM_THREAD_EXECUTION_NOT_HANDLED, pointing towards ACPI.sys.

I noticed that my old installation DID start when I enabled CSM in bios, but not with CSM disabled - even though it is an UEFI installation on a GPT formatted drive.
The same holds true for my new installation: it does boot (and continue with the setup process) when I enable CSM, but not with CSM disabled.

Can somebody shed some light on this?

Installation drive is an SSD connected by SATA (not M2). As stated, the drive is formatted as GPT and includes an EFI bootloader.

[Edit] Additional Info:
Booting works with CSM disabled if CPU virtualization (SVM in BIOS) is disabled. But sadly I do need that feature.

It will also boot with CSM Disabled and SVM Enabled if I Disable IOMMU, but that comes with a performance impact. Just all three do not seem to work together.

Still looking for clues how to resolve this.

Comment: For Windows 11 to run it needs (when starting and started) UEFI, GPT, Secure Boot and TPM V2.   It does not appear to have all it needs.

Comment: Thing is: I do. Secure boot is enabled, and so is the TPM2.0 chip in my Bios (can provide "screen shots" (obviously taken with my phone) if needed). The Disk was freshly formatted by the installation routine (deleted all previous partitions on the drive to make sure) and was formatted with GPT automatically.

Comment: it does boot (and continue with the setup process) when I enable CSM, but not with CSM disabled.   ...   That is legacy boot. Something is strange with your installation

Comment: This I figured, yes. Question is - how do I solve it?

Comment: Especially as Legacy Boot SHOULD also mean SecureBoot is disabled, but both UEFI and Windows (the old installation I can boot into with CSM enabled) show it as enabled and working.

Comment: You may need to reinstall using all the correct parameters at the time of installation.

Comment: This is what I did. I disabled CSM, installed form a thumb drive (CSM disabled should mean it can only boot using UEFI), and the problem persistet with the new installation. And THIS is where things get weird.

Comment: In case it matters: My Mainboard is a Asus PRIME X570-Pro, purchased 2020. Should very well be compatible out of the box.

Comment: For the record: it was correctly installed as UEFI installation. A Bios Update fixed the issue and windows 11 does not start with CSM disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a compatibility issue between your hardware and the UEFI installation of Windows 11.

ACPI.sys is a system file that takes care of power management and other hardware-related functions; because of this, it could be possible that there may be a conflict with your hardware that is causing this error. Enabling CSM in BIOS switches your system into legacy boot mode, which may be more compatible with your hardware.

First, start by checking you meet the minimum system requirements for Windows 11. This means UEFI, TPM v2, and secure boot. You can read more about this here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-11-system-requirements-86c11283-ea52-4782-9efd-7674389a7ba3.

If you meet all of those requirements, consider checking if your BIOS is updated to the latest version, as this might help solve any compatibility issues between your hardware and Windows 11.

Comment: As stated in my question, windows 11 DOES run and start - but I need to ENABLE CSM. Which makes no sense to me at all, as this should disable secure boot, making windows 11 unable to run, but the opposite is true.

Comment: Then the last part of my answer most likely applies here. Have you double checked your BIOS is on the latest version? especially so considering the weirdness around your CSM bios setting.

Comment: I'm about to check for an Update from within the UEFI Utility as we speak, I'll update you if it changes anything.

Comment: A BIOS Update did indeed solve the issue. Thanks for pointing me towards the right direction here.

Comment: Actually, nevermind. The BIOS Update did reset some bios setting. I'm back to "not working" after enableing CPU virtualization again.

So, it also seems to be related to that. Any Input?